# FlytoCart (jQuery Animate) doesn't work with Safari

Tags: jquery, css, safari

I have some code here. It's a FlyToCart effect. It works fine in chrome, firefox and IE. But it doesn't work in safari. Can someone help me?

```js
//Fly to Basket
jQuery('#toBasket').on('click', function() {
  var cart = jQuery('.minibasket-menu');
  var imgtodrag = jQuery('.product-view').find("img").eq(0);
  if (imgtodrag) {
    var imgclone = imgtodrag.clone().offset({
      top: imgtodrag.offset().top,
      left: imgtodrag.offset().left
    }).css({
      'opacity': '0.8',
      'position': 'absolute',
      'height': 'auto',
      'width': '200px',
      'z-index': '100'
    }).appendTo(jQuery('body')).animate({
      'top': cart.offset().top + 50,
      'left': cart.offset().left + 30,
      'width': 75,
      'height': 75
    }, 2000, 'easeInOutExpo');

    imgclone.animate({
      'width': 0,
      'height': 0
    }, 500, function() {
      jQuery(this).detach()
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Please give more information than 'it doesn't work'. What are you expecting to happen? What does happen? Have you debugged this at all? Any errors in the console?

Comment: There is known Webkit issue, when absolute positioning is used with CSS Translate, I have not gone inside the implementation of the animation, but looks like that.

Comment: The arcticle image should fly to the cart icon and fade out.